How to use the RNN layer in Flux.jl?
What am I doing wrong with this Flux.jl NN?
My batch_size=5 and num_features = 1200
Also how does the RNN layer work if I want to input (num_timesteps, num_features)?
Flux.Chain(
    Flux.RNN(num_features, 32, tanh, init=Flux.glorot_normal), 
    Flux.Dropout(0.2),
    Flux.flatten,
    Flux.Dense(32*batch_size, output_size, identity; bias = false)
)

Error:
DimensionMismatch: layer Dense(160 => 1; bias=false) expects size(input, 1) == 160, but got 32×5 Matrix{Float32}

